# Python simpliest If statement with strings not working

Tags: python, string

I am encountering a ridiculous if statement that doesn't accept to do it's job.

I have this :

```
print message
if (message == "left"):
  ser.write("left".encode())
  print message + "sent"
else:
  print message + "not sent"
```

When I print my var "message", before and after, the terminal sends me back

```
left
```

So it should not be a problem...

The only thing that is nearly particular in my case, is that the if statement is nested in 5 other if statements, and above all those if's, a for tag.

I can't find any solution due to how dead simple that looks, sorry for not providing more infos.
Thanks

Comment: What does `print(repr(message ))` output? I think `if message.rstrip() == "left":` might do the trick

Comment: with this code, does anything get printed ("... not sent") ? or nothing at all?

Comment: "left not send" is printed, the else statement works

Comment: print(repr(message )) gives u'left\r\n'

and message.rstrip() worked ! great solution, and strangely, I never saw a space anywhere... thanks a lot !

Comment: When you do `print message + "not sent"`, didn't it put `left` and `not sent` on different lines?

Comment: No worries,  you can add an answer yourself with what worked.

Comment: @ThaoD5 `\n` is a newline, so it should have started a new line after printing `left`.

Comment: It did, strangely, what could be the possible reason to that?

Answer (score 2):

As @Padraic Cunningham 's comment on my post , if that happens to someone : 
`if message.rstrip() == "left":` 
fixed the problem, apparently, some spaces / invisible stuff can troll your if statement, and you !

Thanks @Padraic Cunningham !